# How can I remove Windows 7 from my Mac mini

Tags: bootcamp, windows, parallels-desktop

I recently bought a Mac mini with the latest version Yosemite op system. I installed Parallels and then installed Windows 7 pro using the Windows install disc. I now want to remove Windows 7 all together and just have the Mac op sys but every time I go on Google or Youtube all I see is them talking about Bootcamp. Unless I am mistaken, I do not have bootcamp on my computer.

It should be noted that I am new to Macs so I am treading lightly.

Comment: What version of parallels? That will guide us in showing you the I installation instructions for that app. Once you uninstall parallels, you can reboot and delete the storage of Windows containers  and be done.

Comment: The latest version. I believe its version 11

Answer (score 1):

You have Windows in a virtual machine. This only runs if you run Parallels so Windows is not normally running.

To remove Windows just delete the virtual machine which is just a directory on the disk which by default is ~/Documents/Parallels

If you don't know where the files are then I think in in parallels you will have an option to delete the VM

Answer (score 0):

On Macs you have at least two ways to "install" Windows:

- Installing Windows to a newly created separate partition with Boot Camp Assistant.
- Installing Windows using a type-2 hypervisor like Parallels (or VMware Fusion, VirtualBox etc)

In the first case Windows is directly installed to your disk and interacts with your Mac hardware. In the second case Windows is installed to a disk image residing on your Macintosh volume and interacts with virtual hardware entities provided by the hypervisor. The partition layout of your disk isn't effected then.

One way to detect which kind of Windows installation is present is opening /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility and checking if you have a second partition usually called BOOTCAMP after your Macintosh HD volume.

If such partition is present you have the first type of Windows installation. To delete it open Boot Camp Assistant and remove Windows.
If no such partition is present you probably have the second type of Windows installation. To remove Windows open Parallels and remove the virtual machine Windows (or whatever it is called).